# How to read from a list and print the elements using C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list which consists of different bitmap images as elements. My question is how can I see the content of my list?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your first loop? Why are you trying to write the images into a `txt` file?

Comment: What do you want do with the images? "Print" them like, really print them? Or do you want to save them to a file? Your question is not clear.

Comment: i actually just want to make sure there are elements in my list1. i want to see them;)

Comment: is this the right way of adding new images to my list?

Comment: The fastest way would be a simple breakpoint after your list was created. You can then look into your objects in the VS IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `Count` property then iterate over the images in your list like this:

```
if(list1.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var img in list1)
    {
        pictureBox3.Image = img;
        await Task.Delay(10); // wait 10 millisecond asynchronously
    }
}
```

Note: In order to use `await`, you need to make your method `async`.See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx).

Comment: but how can i see the elements of my list? also can i have a list which the type is <image>?

Comment: what do you want to see ? names ? or do you want to display all images in the picturebox one-by-one ??

Comment: yes actually to display them in my picturebox one-by-one,

Comment: @user3384676 how many seconds do you want to display each image?

Comment: very short delay like 1 millisecond. they have to play continuously,

Comment: Selman22; thank you for your comment, could please tel me how can i save their name or their number as text as well?;)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the elements in your list while debugging, either just check the number of elements in the list, or use a [Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx) that actually shows the image.

The demand for a Bitmap/Image-Visualizer is quite common: [Here's a ready-to-go VS Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0954c361-ae31-491b-a503-926032c79a3d) that provides one or write one yourself (it's actually not that hard).

Example screenshot:

[image]